# Query time suddenly increased

Tags: mysql, datetime, indexing, mariadb, query-performance

I have MariaDB 10.1.14, For a long time I'm doing the following query without problems (it tooks about 3 seconds):

```
SELECT 
    sum(transaction_total) as sum_total, 
    count(*) as count_all, 
    transaction_currency 
FROM 
    transactions 
WHERE 
    DATE(transactions.created_at) = DATE(CURRENT_DATE) 
    AND transaction_type = 1 
    AND transaction_status = 2 
GROUP BY 
    transaction_currency
```

Suddenly, I'm not sure exactly why, this query take about 13 seconds.
This is the EXPLAIN:
[image]

And those are the all indexes of transactions table:
[image]

What is the reason for the sudden query time increase? and how can I decrease it?

Comment: Date funtion at transactions.created_at is taking time mysql wont use indexes if column is enclosed in funtion

Comment: I would say something has definitely changed. So what did you change?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought about that, but the only thing that MAYBE changed is that if AWS upgrade the Maria minor version, but it's not looks like it's updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to answer from @JuanCarlosOropeza, but you can go a little further with the index.

```
ALTER TABLE transactions ADD INDEX (
  transaction_type,
  transaction_status,
  created_at,
  transaction_currency,
  transaction_total
);
```

As @RickJames mentioned in comments, the order of columns is important.

- First, columns in equality comparisons
- Next, you can index *one* column that is used for a range comparison (which is anything besides equality), or GROUP BY or ORDER BY. You have both range comparison and GROUP BY, but you can only get the index to help with one of these.
- Last, other columns needed for the query, if you think you can get a covering index.

I describe more detail about index design in my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really) (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU).

You're probably stuck with the "using temporary" since you have a range condition and also a GROUP BY referencing different columns. But you can at least eliminate the "using filesort" by this trick:

```
...
GROUP BY 
    transaction_currency
ORDER BY NULL
```

Supposing that it's not important to you which order the rows of the query results return in.

Comment: Thanks a lot! the indexing actually help (less than a sec!!!), but.. this is not too specific indexing? I tried to just create index for each column but it give me a slight improvement, also, why this query take so long? And thanks for the great slides and video!

Comment: Is that common/ok to create an index for only one query?

Comment: @Michael Usually the answer is yes, because you want improve response time, but depend on the query. Remember create the index take space and also affect insert and update on that table. So is a trade off. Is up to you to decide if is worthy. Hard Disk space is very cheap so not a real concern.

Comment: Juan is correct. All indexes are created to support specific queries. Hopefully it's a query you run frequently, so you get a lot of value for creating the index. Or else if it's not a frequent query, you need it to be fast when you run it. All optimizations are tradeoffs, so it's up to you to decide if it's worth it to your app.

Answer (score 4):

If you are adding more data to your table the query time will increase.

But you can do a few things to improve the performance.

- Create a composite index for `( transaction_type, transaction_status, created_at)`
- Remove the `DATE()` functions (or any function) from your fields, because that doesn't allow engine use the index. `CURRENT_DATE` is a constant so there doesn't matter, but isn't necessary because already return `DATE`

  - if `created_at` isnt date you can use
  - `created_at >= CURRENT_DATE and created_at  < CURRENT_DATE + 1`
  - or create a different field to only save the date part.

Comment: Your answer is more clear on the problem with `DATE()` than mine. Well explained.

Comment: But the index is backwards.  The "range" part (`created_at`) needs to be last.

Comment: @RickJames Are you sure? Looks ok to me. What would you suggest?

Comment: `AND created_at = CURDATE()` will work with your index.  `created_at >= CURDATE() and created_at  < CURDATE + INTERVAL 1 DAY` will use only as far as `created_at` in the index.  Hence, I suggest moving it to the end.

Comment: @RickJames I have to say not expert on MySql, but in postgresql work ok. Is there a reason the index doesnt work with a range? Also remember we may not be able to use `created_at = CURDATE()` because is possible also have a time component

Comment: "Works OK" is different than "works optimally".  See also http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what has made your query slower. More data? Fragmentation? New DB version?

However, I am surprised to see that there is no index really supporting the query. You should have a compound index starting with the column with highest cardinality (the date? well, you can try different column orders and see which index the DBMS picks for the query).

```
create index idx1 on transactions(created_at, transaction_type, transaction_status);
```

If `created_at` contains a date part, then you may want to create a computed column `created_on` only containing the date and index that instead.

You can even extend this index to a covering index (where clause fields followed by group by clause fields followed by select clause fields):

```
create index idx2 on transactions(created_at, transaction_type, transaction_status,
                                  transaction_currency, transaction_total);
```